# Snowflake Copy Into failing when insert Null in timestamp column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to load file data into Snowflake using COPY INTO. The table has a timestamp column. The file has only Null's empty string "" in that column.

On running copy into with File Format Timestamp option set AUTO, the statement is failing stating Can't parse '' as timestamp.

Is there any way to handle this

Answer (score 2):

Using [NULL_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html) option:

> NULL_IF = ( 'string1' [ , 'string2' ... ] )
>
> String used to convert to and from SQL NULL. Snowflake replaces these strings in the data load source with SQL NULL. To specify more than one string, enclose the list of strings in parentheses and use commas to separate each value.

```
NULL_IF = ('\\N', '')
```

Comment: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Automating-Snowflake-Semi-Structured-JSON-Data-Handling